# can I apply an angularjs ng-repeat directive to pre-rendered server side html elements?

Tags: angularjs

I want to use AngularJS to apply filtering and sorting to a list of div elements, but for SEO reasons, I need this list of divs (and indeed the whole page) to have already been rendered on the page by the back end, in Velocity.

I was hoping using "track by" in the ng-repeat would let me do this by setting the ng-bind attribute on the div tag, and rendering the ng-repeat in each div, so it looks the same as when I inspect the list of divs rendered by AngularJS. both the Velocity context and the AngularJS model contain the same list of devices.

```
#foreach($device in $deviceList)
  <div class="tile" ng-repeat="device in deviceList track by device.model" ng-bind="device.model">
  <span ng-bind="device.brand">${deviceList.brand}</span>
  <span ng-bind="device.model">${deviceList.brand}</span>
</div>
#end
```

but this just renders each item three times. Velocity renders the ng-repeated div, which itself renders for each. the track by doesn't link the identity of each Velocity-rendered div with its own contents.

any ideas?

Comment: Did you have any luck solving this? I'm dealing with the same dilema here... What aproach did you used?