# Apply Angular/Aurelia to pre-rendered page by server

Tags: php, angularjs, aurelia

My problem is using javascript framework like Angular/Aurelia to enhance a pre-rendered page by server (not static HTML page).

I'm implementing a flow that: server (e.g: use PHP) pre-renders some data e.g: a select box with 2 options, then javascript framework will handle things like data binding, http services, ... e.g get more option data and bind to exist select box to render more option tag.

I have tried to use Aurelia with Laravel but I cannot done this implement because I find it's not easy and not comfort to do so. I think there are something wrong with my implement or the way I choose to implement.

Many opinions suggest that use Aurelia/Angular for entire front end and use backend framework like Laravel/Rail just for REST API. But I think it is not good at all. They don't satisfy me. Why drop server template engine on server, it is useful for speed, SEO, ... With Angular/Aurelia, I just use features like data binding, template, formatting, dependency injection, ajax handing, ... I don't use routing feature at all.

The question is: Have anyone have tried this approach? Are there any ways to solve my problem?

p/s: I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318937/can-i-apply-an-angularjs-ng-repeat-directive-to-pre-rendered-server-side-html-el) for my problem, but no one answers it yet.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://patrickwalters.net/enhance-an-existing-page-with-aurelia/